Describe object with both index signature and non-matching specific types in TypeScript
I am attempting to create typings for an existing JavaScript library (the library itself cannot be changed). I will not be the only user of these typings, so I cannot enforce hacks around the typing system (e.g. adding as ... after variable assignments).
The library makes wide use of flat configuration objects, where a defined set of properties configure specific things, and any additional properties are collected as additional configuration. An imagined example could be a configuration for a form:
type InputConfiguration = 
  | { type: "TEXT", defaultValue?: string }
  | { type: "CHECKBOX", defaultValue?: boolean };

type FormConfiguration = {
  title: string,        // the title of the form
  horizontal?: boolean, // whether to display the form horizontally
  // any additional properties specify the input elements in the form
  [inputName: string]: InputConfiguration
}

This does not work in TypeScript, failing with Property 'title' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'InputConfiguration'. TypeScript considers the index type to match all strings, and doesn't support specific properties diverging from that.
Setting aside the design problems this design has, it happens to be how the library works, and isn't particularly complex. I have been unable to find a way to describe it in TypeScript, however.
My question therefore is: how do I describe this "arbitrary keys, except for the ones specified, have type X" in TypeScript?.

I've tried simply defining the index signature and specific types:
type FormConfiguration = {
  title: string, // Property 'title' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'InputConfiguration'.
  [inputName: string]: InputConfiguration
}

I've tried defining it as an intersection of two types:
type FormConfiguration = {
  title: string,
} & {
  [inputName: string]: InputConfiguration
}
// Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FormConfiguration'.
//   Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [inputName: string]: InputConfiguration; }'.
//     Property 'title' is incompatible with index signature.
//       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'InputConfiguration'.
const foo: FormConfiguration = {
  title: "bar",
  foo: { type: "TEXT" },
};

(plus a variety of other ways that didn't turn up anything useful)

This isn't possible in TS. Go upvote ms/TS#17867 and see the linked question/answer for various workarounds.
